# How to store a variable across lambda invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to store a variable containing a URL across invocations of my function, and to be able to modify this variable from inside the function. So in short I need to be able to send this URL to the function, and be able to retrieve it later. I've created a bucket I could store the URL in, but I'm having a real hard time understanding the documentation on how to write to and read from the bucket using lambda. Using the bucket or some other method, how would I store this piece of data? I'm using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, which depend on exactly how the URL is shared, accessed, how often you read/write it.

For **infrequent access**, e.g., you lambda executes once a minute, you can store it in [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

For **high frequencies** and concurrent access, probably you should consider using [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html).

S3 can also be used, but it will be the slowest and requires a bit of setup to read and write from your lambda. Access to parameter store is rather simple, as you can use [get_parameter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameter) boto3 sdk.

Comment: The parameter store worked quite well and was far easier to understand, thank you.